# 'Missing' fixed effect in linear mixed model output

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, matlab

In the Matlab linear mixed-effects model [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlme.html), the example included below is provided. Here, there are five types of tomatoes (vine, grape, heirloom, cherry, plum) and four types of fertiliser (1,2,3,4). What I don't understand is why in the fixed effects coefficients output, cherry and fertiliser 1 are not included. Is this a Matlab quirk or is there a good statistical explanation for this?

```
lme = 


Linear mixed-effects model fit by ML

Model information:
    Number of observations              60
    Fixed effects coefficients          20
    Random effects coefficients         18
    Covariance parameters                3

Formula:
    Yield ~ 1 + Tomato*Fertilizer + (1 | Soil) + (1 | Soil:Tomato)

Model fit statistics:
    AIC       BIC       LogLikelihood    Deviance
    522.57    570.74    -238.29          476.57  

Fixed effects coefficients (95% CIs):
    Name                                  Estimate    SE        tStat       DF
    '(Intercept)'                              77     8.5836      8.9706    40
    'Tomato_Grape'                            -16     11.966     -1.3371    40
    'Tomato_Heirloom'                     -6.6667     11.966    -0.55714    40
    'Tomato_Plum'                          32.333     11.966      2.7022    40
    'Tomato_Vine'                             -13     11.966     -1.0864    40
    'Fertilizer_2'                         34.667      8.572      4.0442    40
    'Fertilizer_3'                         33.667      8.572      3.9275    40
    'Fertilizer_4'                         47.667      8.572      5.5607    40
    'Tomato_Grape:Fertilizer_2'           -2.6667     12.123    -0.21997    40
    'Tomato_Heirloom:Fertilizer_2'             -8     12.123    -0.65992    40
    'Tomato_Plum:Fertilizer_2'                -15     12.123     -1.2374    40
    'Tomato_Vine:Fertilizer_2'                -16     12.123     -1.3198    40
    'Tomato_Grape:Fertilizer_3'            16.667     12.123      1.3748    40
    'Tomato_Heirloom:Fertilizer_3'         3.3333     12.123     0.27497    40
    'Tomato_Plum:Fertilizer_3'             3.6667     12.123     0.30246    40
    'Tomato_Vine:Fertilizer_3'                  3     12.123     0.24747    40
    'Tomato_Grape:Fertilizer_4'            13.333     12.123      1.0999    40
    'Tomato_Heirloom:Fertilizer_4'            -19     12.123     -1.5673    40
    'Tomato_Plum:Fertilizer_4'            -2.6667     12.123    -0.21997    40
    'Tomato_Vine:Fertilizer_4'             8.6667     12.123     0.71492    40


    pValue        Lower      Upper 
    4.0206e-11     59.652    94.348
       0.18873    -40.184    8.1837
       0.58053     -30.85    17.517
      0.010059     8.1496    56.517
       0.28379    -37.184    11.184
    0.00023272     17.342    51.991
    0.00033057     16.342    50.991
    1.9567e-06     30.342    64.991
       0.82701    -27.167    21.834
       0.51309    -32.501    16.501
       0.22317    -39.501    9.5007
       0.19439    -40.501    8.5007
       0.17683    -7.8341    41.167
       0.78476    -21.167    27.834
       0.76387    -20.834    28.167
       0.80581    -21.501    27.501
       0.27796    -11.167    37.834
       0.12492    -43.501    5.5007
       0.82701    -27.167    21.834
       0.47881    -15.834    33.167

Random effects covariance parameters (95% CIs):
Group: Soil (3 Levels)
    Name1                Name2                Type         Estimate    Lower  
    '(Intercept)'        '(Intercept)'        'std'        2.5028      0.02771


    Upper 
    226.05

Group: Soil:Tomato (15 Levels)
    Name1                Name2                Type         Estimate    Lower 
    '(Intercept)'        '(Intercept)'        'std'        10.225      6.1497


    Upper 
    17.001

Group: Error
    Name             Estimate    Lower     Upper 
    'Res Std'        10.499      8.5389    12.908
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a regression where you have 2 categorical predictors (tomato and fertilizer), you have to dummy-code them in order to do a regression. That means that, in this case, for one 5-value categorical variable (tomato) you create 4 variables with values 1 or 0, to cover all posibilities (regression cannot work with numbers 1,2,3,4,5 if they represent different categories, it can only work with 1/0 where 0 represents one reference category and 1 represents some other category). In your case, both cherry and fertilizer 1 are reference categories.

'(Intercept)'  gives you the value of Yield when tomatos are cherry and fertilizer is 1. Then 'Tomato_Grape' gives you the value of Yield when tomatos are Grape and fertilizer is 1 etc.

For more info on dummy coding look at: [Link1](http://www.statisticssolutions.com/dummy-coding-the-how-and-why/).
For understanding how to interpret the interaction between two categorical variables based on dummy coding look at [Interaction](https://tomhouslay.com/2014/09/06/understanding-3-way-interactions-between-continuous-and-categorical-variables-small-multiples/)